# Is network flair broken or is it just me?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, flair, combined-flair

From the about me section of my profile:

[image: About me in my profile with no image found as flair]

When I go to my network profile's flair tab ([which is also broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yLmW.png)) I get following code:

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/2016507/vogel612">
    <img src="https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2016507.png" width="208" height="58" 
    alt="profile for Vogel612 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" title="profile for Vogel612 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&amp;A sites" />
</a>
```

which is broken (as can be seen when I paste this right below:

[image: profile for Vogel612 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Manually navigating to the link given gets me to "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

now... is it just me, or is the network-wide flair currently borken?

And if it's just me, could that be because I hid some of my "top communities" with the new feature?

Comment: Interestingly, it shows up just fine now. I guess they fixed it.